# Measure inactivity time

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'd like to implement a rather simple functionality that would log the user out of the Windows Store app after a certain inactivity timeout expires.

What would be the best way to achieve this?
I don't want to "manually" subscribe to all the touch, mouse and keyboard events at the app level, that's ugly. There must be some event I can subscribe to in App.xaml.cs, I want to hope :-)